# How to load textures in away3d runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, runtime, textures, away3d

I am working on a big 3d model. I want to load its textures once all 3d files has loaded and rendered. So that i load textures one by one and apply them on models. Does anyone knows how to achieve runtime textures loading and applying using actionscript away3d.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) queues to load all my assets. You could setup one that loads all your bitmaps. You can then listen for individual items load complete or all items load complete and then create your materials and assign them to your meshes.

Also, you need to recursively assign the material to a mesh's SubMeshes ( see subMeshes : Vector. in the [Mesh Class](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/entities/Mesh.html)) for it to update.